# printf scanf function and fflush()

Tags: c, printf, scanf, format-specifiers

When I use `printf()` function followed by `scanf()` one I get in trouble.
I write below the code and the eclipse compiler says that there are no errors and no warning, but when I compile it it shows: `insert array dimension insert array elements`. It does not make me insert anything and the program ends. 
I've also tried to add `fflush(stdout)` but nothing changes.
What can I do?

```
int main(void) {
    int *V;
    int i;
    int N;
    printf("insert array dimension");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%n", &N);
    V=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
    if(V==NULL){
        printf("\n error");
        fflush(stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\ninsert array elements");
    fflush(stdout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why you are using `%n` specifier for `int` ?

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. And always `free` allocated memory.

Comment: `scanf` is considered evil because it does two tasks and leaves the input stream in an unknown state upon error. Use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` if you want to ensure you know just how much input has been read.

Comment: Even after adding the header files you omitted `gcc -Wall` reports `junk.c:7:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’`. You need to increase the Eclipse error options. Also, no warnings or errors only means that you didn't annoy the compiler; in C that is almost no comfort at all.

Comment: ok yess I made a mistake with %n instead of %d thanks

Comment: however it doesn't work if I don't put setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); function, that's the solution.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - Change `scanf("%n", &N);` to `scanf("%d", &N);`

---

To quote the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2, `fscanf()`, for the format specifier (*emphasis mine*)

> `n`
>  No input is consumed. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   signed integer **into which is to be written the number of characters read from
>   the input stream so far by this call** to the `fscanf` function. Execution of a
>   `%n` directive **does not increment the assignment count returned at the
>   completion of execution** of the `fscanf` function. No argument is converted,
>   but one is consumed. If the conversion specification includes an assignment suppressing
>   character or a field width, the behavior is undefined.

So, basically,

```
 scanf("%n", &N);
```

does not store the *input* value to `N`, rather it try to store the *"number of characters read from
the input stream so far"*, which is likely to be 0, in your case.

So, later in case of `malloc()`, if you pass a 0 size, it can either return a NULL or a pointer that can **only be passed to `free()`**. Using that pointer later will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You could have been able to debug the issue if you would have checked the returnvalue of `scanf()` in first place.

You need to have the correct format specifier for an `int`, the `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

Converting this line scanf("%n", &N); with scanf("%d", &N); works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change '%n' with '%d'

```
int main(void) {

int *V;
int i;
int N;
printf("insert array dimension");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &N);
V=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
if(V==NULL){
    printf("\n error");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
printf("\ninsert array elements");
fflush(stdout);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```